# Find an integer value inside a string

Tags: c#

I'm looking to find the integer value inside the following string:

"value="5412304756756756756756792114343986"

How can I do this using C#?

Comment: Is the `"` within the string intentional?

Comment: Do you want the numeric part to be an integer type or is a string what you are after? Because that value looks far too big to be an `int`

Comment: @SteveHaigh It is in fact too big even to be a `long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex to find the number in a string:

```
var resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

For negative values:

```
var resultString = Regex.Match(yourString, @"(|-)\d+").Value;
```

Comment: Might not be enough with a possible negative sign etc.

Comment: Use Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(yourString, @"(|-)\d+").Value) for negative values as mentioned by @PLB

Answer (score 2):

You can look for the equals sign...

```
string yourString = "value=5412304756756756756756792114343986";
string integerPart = yourString.Split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [char.IsDigi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5kahff.aspx)t
Something like .

```
string str = "value=5412304756756756756756792114343986";
List<char> justDigits = new List<char>();
foreach(char c in str)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(c))
        justDigits.Add(c);
}

string intValues = new string(justDigits.ToArray());
```

Or **Shorter version**

```
string intValues = new string(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: Too lengthy, and time consuming

Comment: @Anandkumar, what about the shorter version ?

Comment: Habib sir, shorter version is super one sir...... But my question is which one is good as comparing to @Preben Huybrechts answer
i.e. var resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;

Comment: @Anandkumar, I am not a big fan or regex and personally lack the ability to even form a simple one :P so can't really comment, but usually yes, Regex should do better - I assume

Comment: One up for a non-regex solution. Note that the solution in this answer performs far better than the regex one. Not a problem if you just process a couple of strings. But if performance is crucial (and there are millions of strings to process) I would definitively prefer this version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex`:

```
int IntVal = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(yourString, @"(|-)\d+").Value);
```

This will match negative numbers too. You could also iterate over every character in string and check id they are numerical but not really desirable solution because it can be a bottleneck.

**Edit:** In your input number is larger than long. For numbers like this, you can use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx), from framework 4.0 onwards

Comment: int IntVal = Int32 will not work for "5412304756756756756756792114343986"

Answer (score 1):

```
        Match match = new Regex("[0-9]+").Match("value=\"5412304756756756756756792114343986\"");
        while(match.Success)
        {
            // Do something
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
```